# HMACMD5 in .net compact framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, cryptography

How to implement HMACMD5 algorithm in .net compact framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cfAES](http://www.mperfect.net/cfAes/) supports HMACMD5 and is written for the .NET Compact Framework.